# Database design naming: should use "id" or "table_name" + "id"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

So, for each table there is a id, generally it is int(11) Auto inc, not null.

When I was in school I mainly named it as id,

However, when I encounter the more complex database design , I found if I use "id", I have to do more in the Select Query

For example, there is a table "customer", "customer_group"

So I simply get the customer and his customer_group info like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
JOIN customer_group 
    ON customer.group_id = customer_group.id
```

Notice that there will be two id return, if I would like differentiate them, I need to do:

```
SELECT customer.id AS cid
    ,customer_group_id AS cgid
    ,customer.NAME
    ,.......
FROM customer
JOIN customer_group 
    ON customer.group_id = customer_group.id
```

That makes the work very tedious and the query is long. So, I wonder what is the practice in naming the id, should I use table_name + "id" to name it? Thanks

Comment: Both ways work as long as you are consistent. Other than that it's a religious debate.

Comment: Thanks. it seems the table_name + id makes the query shorter , however, why some database still use id ? Do you mean there is the way for the "id" apporach can overcome this problem

Comment: `table_name_id` is only shorter if you don't use aliases (e.g. `tn.id`). Both approaches have their pros and cons, and both get the job done - just a bit differently.

Comment: As a sidebar to your discussion, I'm going to note that giving every table an id field populated by autonumber reflects a compromise between the relational model of data and the graph model of data.  FKs that reference an id field are indirect pointers.  This is true regardless of how the id field is named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do something like this using [aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/), to make it less tedious and more readable..

```
SELECT c.id AS cid
    ,customer_group_id AS cgid
    ,c.NAME
    ,.......
FROM customer c
JOIN customer_group cg
    ON c.group_id = cg.id
```

In Case of Naming the ID the best practice of ID is opinion based, or implementation standard based. Per situation the benefits varies on each method.

Generally, the `ID` of a  `X Table` should be `ID` but when it is used in other table lets say `Y Table` as foreign key it will become `X_ID`

So, this will make things clear in the Y table that this X_ID refers to(coming from) X table's `ID`

Naming conventions are defined as per convenience of developers then it becomes methodology and later-on it will become standard.
But, this also affects us with the change in development environment..

I will suggest if its commercial project choose naming convention as per the standard.

If personal project, choose what suits your habits..